# What are the two components of this waveform generated by a MS-15 hall effect current sensor?

Tags: waveform, current-sensing

I am doing a lab write up for school in which we measured the output of a current sensor which was part of a power supply we are using with our ELVIS boards. Here is a schematic of the basic design showing a transformer at the top and the current sensor/source at the bottom. I highlighted the wire where we took our data.

[image: schematic of power supply]

We then used an oscilloscope to capture the output waveform. Here are the results from the data
[image: Current sensor wave form]

Part of my assignment is describing "both parts" of the waveform. I believe this is referring to the peak and then the following square wave. Me and my partner believe that the square wave is generated as a result of the hall effect, but to be totally honest we do not know. Nothing so far in our class or research has indicated to us what could be causing the peak.

Any clues? Sorry the question is somewhat vague, but I have not been able to find any information regarding the waveform.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

+/-0.5 voltage resembles a diode drop, of a diode bridge with no load except small capacitance in parallel with the output of the voltage gain of your CCVS =0.1 or an opto-coupled photo diode IC with a pull-up resistor on output that has very little LED current so not quite saturating .  Optocoupler diodes have an hFE of 0.1 typ.  Optocoupled transistors have a gain of 1 typ. but greater variation. These parts usually have 3-5kV isolation.

Most likely one of **[these](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/isolators/optoisolators-transistor-photovoltaic-output/3736383?k=opto&k=&pkeyword=opto&pv598=40&pv598=48&pv598=54&pv598=284&FV=fff40039%2Cfff8033f&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=500)** parts.

It looks like your gnd reference is after the full Si diode bridge with 0.5V drop and no current .